# Data Processing / Mining Question

Tags: database, data-mining

I'm starting to work on a financial information website (somewhat like google finance or bloomberg).
My website needs to display live currency, commodity, and stock values. I know how to do this frontend-wize, but I have a backend data storing question (I already have the data feed APIs):
How would you guys go about this - would you set up your own database and save all the data in the db with some kind of a backend worker, and then plug in your frontend to your db, or would you plug your frontend directly to the API and not mine the data?
Mining the data could be good for later reference (statistics and other things that the API wont allow), but can such a big quantity of ever growing information be stored on a database?  Is this feasible? What other things should I be considering?

Thank you - any comment would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd cleanly separate the front end from the code that reads the source APIs. Having done that, I could have the code that reads the source APIs feed the front end directly, feed a database, or both.

I'm a database guy. I'd lean toward feeding data from the APIs into a database, and connecting the front end to the database. But it really depends on the application's requirements.

Feeding a database makes it simple and cheap to change your mind.  If you (or whoever) decides later to keep no historical data, just delete old data after storing new data. If you (or whoever) decides later to keep all historical data, just don't delete old data.

Feeding a database also gives you fine-grained control over who gets to see the data, relatively independent of their network operating system permissions. Depending on the application, this may or may not be a good thing.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I have some DB experience (MSSQL and SQLite) but not with large amounts of data / with a focus on optimization.  Could you please recommend a DB engine (I think MySQL would be best here)? I also heard that data caching will be necessary. Any pointers to documentation / books I can read to get acquainted with dbs would be much appreciated! Thank you again!3

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL are the most widely used, server-based, open source SQL database management systems. You can install both and test them using your own sample data. A cache might be necessary; might not. Search StackOverflow for "database design books".